# When use Dynamic Soql ,I query all Records,But I want Queryed records are limited to the permissions of the shared table or Data Auth

Tags: soql

Two Users, A and B.
Two Leads, l1 and l2,  The owner of l1 is A.The owner of l2 is B.
When I Use A's account.

```
List<Lead> leadList = [select id from Lead];
// query l1 record
List<Lead> leadList2 = Database.query('select id from Lead');
// query all Row  include l1,l2
```

I want to use Database.query function with data auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem

```
public with share A
```

and

```
public with share
```

They are different

detail：https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_security_sharing_rules.htm

Answer (score 1):

Use [Security.stripInaccessible](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_with_security_stripInaccessible.htm) on the results to remove fields and records the user cannot see. Also, if you use `with sharing` or `inherited sharing` on a class, record-level access is automatically enforced, so the query would only return records they can view.